# Same Product Different Image In Category

Tags: magento2, product-images, category-products

I Have a product for example, **t-shirt that is added to men's category and women's category**. Now I want to display a **t-shirt with woman's image in women's category** & **t-shirt with man's image in men's category**.

Is there any possibility for the above **without creating the same product again**.

If possible kindly provide idea for it.

Comment: Try once the idea of @sduif.

Answer (score 2):

If I had to make this I would do it the following way:

1. Create new product image attributes for the women and man categories (Stores -> Attributes -> Product)
2. Create a module that adds an attribute to the category entity to allow the user to select which type of image should be shown in each category (Man, Women)
3. Write logic where needed to show the right image (list.phtml, etc)

Comment: any steps i can follow ?